# Creating Date Cutoffs on continuous processes

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I'm an intern databasing some CNC machine metrics and i'm a little stuck with a particular query, only started sql last week so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

If a machine is running (state=on) past date,23:59, and I want to collect machine hours for that day, there is no logged off time, as the state=off column has not been recorded yet, thus I cannot collect that machine data. To work around this, I want to record a state off time of 23:59:59, and then create a new row with the same entity ID with a state_on time of day+1,00:00:01.

Here is what I have written so far, where am I going wrong? What combination of trigger, insert, procedure, case, etc should I use? Any suggestions are welcome, I've tried to look at some reference material, and want the first bit to look something like this.

```
CASE
  WHEN min(stoff.last_changed) IS NULL 
        AND now() = '____-__-__ 23:59:59.062538+13'
    THEN min(stoff.last_changed) IS now()
  ELSE min(stoff.last_changed)
END
```

I know this is only the first component, but it fits into a larger select used within a view,let me know if I need to post anything else

Comment: You can do this all in a query (no triggers, inserts etc needed) but for a query calculating runtime for a device that turns on/off multiple times in a day I'd usually use window functions (fairly advanced SQL). This may not be neccessary; it really depends on what data is available to you. Your current code is difficult to follow without more context; perhaps you could add sufficient detail to make a working example https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=43hLAx4D4J provides a starter with a modified version of the code above (it provides a result but its wrong!).

Comment: Thanks so much @brits

Comment: Thanks so much! I put the SQL there that deals directly with our DB, which is really just pairing entity_id's with an on/off state column and comparing the times between timestamps (giving elapsed time between state changes). What I would like to achieve is creating a table that refreshes via day, in other words if a machine had no reported off state change for 3 days, then it would have entries on 3 rows that are all representative of the machine being on in one particular day. Hope that's a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex query because there are a few possibilities you need to consider (given the physical setup of the CNC machine these may not both apply:

- The machine might be running at midnight so you need to 'insert' a midnight start time (and treat midnight as the stop time for the previous day).
- The machine might be running all day (so there are no records in your table for the day at all)

There are a number of ways you can implement this; I have chosen one that I think will be easiest for you to understand (and have avoided window functions). The response does use [CTE's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) but I think these are easy enough to understand (it's really just a chain of queries; each one using the result of the previous one).

Lets setup some example data:

```
create table states (
  entity_id int,
  last_changed timestamp,
  state bool
  );

insert into states(entity_id, last_changed, state) values
(1, '2019-11-26 01:00', false),
(1, '2019-11-26 20:00', true),
(1, '2019-11-27 01:00', false),
(1, '2019-11-27 02:00', true),
(1, '2019-11-27 22:00', false);
```

Now the query (it's not as bad as it looks!):

```
 -- Lets start with a range of dates that you want the report for (needed because its possible that there are 
 -- no entries at all in the states table for a particular date)    
with date_range as (
    select i::date from generate_series('2019-11-26', '2019-11-29', '1 day'::interval) i
),
-- Get all combinations of machine (entity_id) and date
allMachineDays as (
    select  distinct states.entity_id, date_range.i as started
    from 
    states cross join date_range),
-- Work out what the state at the start of each day was (if no earlier state available then assume false)
stateAtStartOfDay as (
    select 
        entity_id, started, 
        COALESCE(
            (
                select state 
                from states 
                where states.entity_id = allMachineDays.entity_id 
                    and states.last_changed<=allMachineDays.started 
                order by states.last_changed desc limit 1
            )
            ,false) as state
   from allMachineDays
)
,
-- Now we can add in the state at the start of each day to the other state changes
statesIncludingStartOfDay as (
    select * from stateAtStartOfDay 
    union 
    select * from states
),
-- Next we add the time that the state changed
statesWithEnd as (
    select
        entity_id, 
        state,
        started,
        (
            select started from statesIncludingStartOfDay substate
             where 
             substate.entity_id = states.entity_id and 
             substate.started  > states.started
             order by started asc
             limit 1
         ) as ended
    from 
    statesIncludingStartOfDay states
)
-- finally lets work out the duration
select
    entity_id, 
    state,
    started,
    ended,
    ended - started as duration
from 
    statesWithEnd states
where 
    ended is not null -- cut off the last midnight as its no longer needed
order by entity_id,started
```

Hopefully this makes sense and there are no errors in my logic! Note that I have made some assumptions about your data (i.e. last_changed is the time that the state began). If you just want a runtime for each day it's pretty easy to just add a group by to the last query and sum up duration.

It might help you to understand this if you run it one step at a time; gor example start with the following and then add in extra with clauses one at a time:

```
with date_range as (
    select i::date from generate_series('2019-11-26', '2019-11-29', '1 day'::interval) i
)
select * from date_range
```

Comment: That was easy enough to understand, thanks again for taking the time to help ! I ended up seeking help from a colleague, and it turns out we came up with something largely the same as what you did. For anyone who is having a similar problem, we wrote a table with all the possible combinations of weekday, work hours (ie. staffed vs non) and cross joined that to our table with last_Changed, categorising any on duration as one of the possible rows in the table